# Using react-mapbox-gl (react) to make 'search this area' of google

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm a new of MapBox and trying to make the same feature of googleMap 'Search This Area'.

In my imagine, I need the coordinate of user's view(left-top and right-bottom), then I can calculate if my points is in user's view it will display markers.

```
pointlat, pointlng, lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2

pointlat > lat1 && pointlat < lat2
pointlng > lng1 && pointlng < lng2
```

Are there any ways to get the coordinate of user view's left-top and right-bottom using `react-mapbox-gl` or `mapbox-gl-js`? Or other ways to make this feature possible?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/geography/#lnglatbounds
to get the bounding box of your current map view, use

```
map.getBounds()
```

or use something like

```
map.getBounds().contains(myMarker.getLatLng())
```

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/local-search-geocoding-api/#the-bbox-parameter

you can pass the geocoder a bbox, to restrain the search within (from mapbox examples):

```
var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({ // Initialize the geocoder
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken, // Set the access token
    mapboxgl: mapboxgl, // Set the mapbox-gl instance
    marker: false, // Do not use the default marker style
    placeholder: 'Search for places in Berkeley', // Placeholder text for the search bar
    bbox: [-122.30937, 37.84214, -122.23715, 37.89838], // Boundary for Berkeley
    proximity: {
      longitude: -122.25948,
      latitude: 37.87221
    } // Coordinates of UC Berkeley
  });
```

this should point you in the right direction, I hope

Comment: @janw thank you for your feedback :), i hope the edit made it more of an acceptable answer